# Find a family of functions $f_{k,n}(z)$ with $f_{k,n}(z) = \frac{n}{k} \cdot z \cdot f^{'}_{k+1,n}(z) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, functional-equations

I need some hints or keywords for the following problem: I am looking for a family $f_{k,n}(z)$ of functions ($k,n \in \mathbb{N}$) in $z \in [0,1]$, which satisfy the following functional/differential equation:
$$ f_{k,n}(z) = \frac{n}{k} \cdot z \cdot f^{'}_{k+1,n}(z) \,,\qquad (z \in (0,1)) $$
with $f_{k,n}(0)=0$ and $f_{k,n}(1) = 1$ for all $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Because of the shift k+1 in the parameter and the conditions at $0$ and $1$, I cant (or dont know) how to solve this.

Without the conditions at $z=0$ and $z=1$ I got a solution for $z \in [0,1)$, but these conditions are really important for my problem.

Does anyone know any good keywords I should search for to solve such equations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that without the boundary condition at $1$, you can choose $f_{1,n}(z)$ however you want and inductively set $f_{k+1,n}(z)=\int_0^z\frac{k}{nt}f_{k,n}(t)\;dt$. The boundary condition at $1$ translates to $\int_0^1(-\ln z)^kf_{1,n}'(z)\;dz=n^k$.

Comment: Thanks stewbasic for your answer. But then it seems already problematic in the case $n=1$ to satisfy this condition doesn't it?